# How do you use a variable declared in a directive in a Directive Definition Object's template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here's my simple directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
     var someVar = "Yodelayheehoo";

     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: "<p>The var is: {{someVar}}</p>"
     }
});
```

I tried this, but `someVar` doesn't print out.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someVar` has to be property of the scope object not just local variable:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: "<p>The var is: {{someVar}}</p>",
          link: function(scope) {
              scope.someVar = "Yodelayheehoo";
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: As a sub question, what if I want to pass `someVar` to a different directive? For example `<my-direc theVar='someVar'></my-direc>`? I'm trying to do it like this but it's not working